# Add all possible record as association

Tags: ruby, associations, sequel

**Question**: Is there opposite of remove_all_ in Ruby Sequel

**Background**: I have two models (let's say *car* and *factory* ) with association between them. I am able to remove all cars from factory (`factory.remove_all_cars`) but in front-end user also has option to mark checkbox for associating all *cars*. In such case i need in my model something like `factory.add_all_cars`

Comment: I tried to call `.add_all_cars` and google for "ruby sequel opposite of remove_all_". Atm i have it implemented by own each block, but it does not seems to me like THE way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
factory.
  class.
  association_reflection(:cars).
  associated_dataset.
  all{|car| factory.add_car(car)}
```

The reason there is no `add_all_cars` method is because few people need such a feature.  This is the first time I've seen a request for such a method in the more than 5 years I've been maintaining Sequel.